# Connecting dryer vent in new window

Tags: vent, dryer, exhaust-vent

We just had some old windows replaced with glass block in the basement. The installers added a window with an attachment to vent the clothes dryer but, of course, it's different to the one in the old window. Here's what they left us with:

[image]

I have the bendy metal pipe going from the dryer to a flexible metal elbow that then connected to a straight piece of steel pipe that (use to) vent to the outside. Of course the metal pipe doesn't fit over that plastic ring. It will fit inside (with a bit of persuasion), but isn't tight enough to stay. I don't know if it's a good idea to try a metal clamp over the plastic ring as I fear it might crack the plastic, and there isn't really a lot of room around the ring.

What would be the appropriate piece of kit to mate the plastic ring there to my tube coming from my dryer?

Comment: If you can get the duct inside the ring, a bit of foil tape should hold it in place. Are there any screw holes in the ring? Does the ring, or any bit of the assembly come out of the surrounding (i.e. is any part of this thing removable)?

Comment: @Tester101: Really? Tape seems so cheap and cheerful.

Comment: Not just any tape, you have to use HVAC foil tape. It's rated for high temperature applications, and it's stickier than hell. It's probably not the "proper" way, but it should work.

Comment: @Tester101: It doesn't appear to be removable and I don't see any screw holes. There does appear to be a lip around the beveled square part which made me wonder if there's supposed to be something that snaps into that.

Comment: Screws in dryer vents are not advisable, at least on all the jobs the HVAC guys did the running of the ductwork through out the house. The tips of the screws catch the lint and will not be good. The tape Testor refers is the ONLY thing to use.

Comment: The cut-out on the bottom makes me think that there's a coupler missing.  Was it new when they installed it? It looks like it has lint on it already, but it's hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: @Comintern: No it's new. The marks are from where I was trying to figure out how to jam the existing tube in there. For the time being I've hooked it up with tape, but I think I might have to contact the installers and ask if they forgot to give me a piece.

Comment: Is it like that on the other side too?

Comment: @aaron: No, the other side just has your normal louvered vents

Comment: @MattBurland Old post I answered. What solution did you use?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use large hose clamps as HVAC tape is not designed to hold the weight of the flex-duct or metal elbow and pipe or flex-duct. Use the HVAC tape to connect flex-duct pipe or elbows only. You need to have a removable link between the vent and ductwork for occassional cleaning.

The vent is a stand alone part. There are other parts to to complete this. Likely the installers were only concerned about the window. Granted that was 6 years ago, but a [search](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B8XF6PM) online (U.S.) shows there are other parts to go with this.
[image: Glass Block Dryer Vent parts]